# php msql count increment

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get multiple items from my mysql data base I HAVE NO PROBLEM HERE

`"SELECT * FROM phpbb_phpb809posts WHERE forum_id = 2 ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 4";`

as you can see i get four items from the database i then display the fields i pulled and display all of them descending from the newest to the oldest.

What i'm trying to do is display a number, say 1 and increment it by 1 for each one so:

title1 (pulled from DB)

content1 (pulled from DB)

Date (pulled from DB)

post number "1" (generated by server)

```
<hr/>
```

title2 (pulled from DB)

content2 (pulled from DB)

Date (pulled from DB)

post number "2" (generated by server itself)

```
<hr/>
```

title3 (pulled from DB)

and so on... i'm not very good with php but i've searched and i cant  seem to find what i'm looking for it might not be possible but it seems  to be like something that should be

Comment: Can you post your so far tried effort ?

Comment: Very simple. Run a variable to store the number of iterations of your loop starting with 1 and increment every time. Displaying that will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: seems simple but i have no idea how to do this could you help get me started

Comment: to downvotes, sorry i annoyed you with my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some php-pseudo(since i don't know if you are using pdo or mysqli) answer shall be

```
   executeTheQuery("SELECT * FROM phpbb_phpb809posts WHERE forum_id = 1 ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 4");
   $result = getTheSelectedItems($query);  
   $i = 0;

    while($tables = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $currentRow = getCurrRow($tables);
        echo "$currentRow mynumber = $i";
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry just says mynumber = 0 for each one

Comment: then you have done something wrong, what are you using pdo or mysqli?

Comment: got it, works perfectly, using mysql i just had trouble understanding how it worked, but i played around with it, and figured it out, your answer works great

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :

```
"SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS postnumber, * FROM phpbb_phpb809posts
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
 WHERE forum_id = 2 ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 4";
```